# How to use port 8443 with ECS Fargate and ALB?

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-ecs, nginx-reverse-proxy, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

Is it possible to run spring boot containerized apps on port 8443 going through a 443 ALB listener and deployed on ECS Fargate in AWS? The 443 listener would have an issued cert, not a self-signed cert. I would use an NLB but I need to set route paths, so that's a no go. Would using nginx as a proxy be used in a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run spring boot containerized apps on port 8443
> going through a 443 ALB listener and deployed on ECS Fargate in AWS?

Yes it is absolutely possible, there should be no issue with this at all. What you are describing is actually just a very standard and basic ECS/Fargate setup.

> Would using nginx as a proxy be used in a situation like this?

Only if you want to. You don't need Nginx just to make this work.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I think I got it. I add the yaml file in Spring boot an ssl block, then created a jks file from the pem and .cer. Updated the dockerfile and env vars in the gradle build to include port 8443 and then updated the IaC for https. EVeryrthing works now.